# Is the myspace streaming subscription API still functional, and if so, how can I tell?

Tags: api, streaming, subscription, myspace

In an effort to get music-related events for an app we're building, we've mulled through Myspace's decidedly clunky authentication process and managed to set up a subscription and endpoint.

Using all this fun stuff:

http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:Real_Time_Stream
http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Stream_Subscription_API
http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Stream_Subscription_Example_Walkthrough

The Myspace GET request verifies the existence of our subscription.  So all we were hoping to do was sit back and wait...

...but even with no query filtering set whatsoever (i.e. we should get EVERYTHING that happens!), we seem to get no data pushed our way.

Most worrisome is that I don't see anyone talking about this on the web anytime recently.  Does it still exist?  It's still on Myspace's Developer homepage.  Did they forget to take it down?  Is their sense of self-esteem so low at this point (for obvious reasons) that they've stopped caring about whether their services work?

A boolean answer with conclusive supporting evidence would be most appreciated.

Links to resources and discussions less than a year old would be an awesome bonus.

Comment: Perchance new API is being developed: [**Justin Timberlake purchases Myspace for 35M**](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jun/30/myspace-internet). After the read, head over to the [**MySpace Developer Center**](http://developer.myspace.com/) to check out anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myspace has a very inactive [**MySpace Developer Team News and Announcements**](http://developer.myspace.com/community/blogs/devteam/default.aspx)  that lists various **API modules** designed to work with the `ActivityStrea.ms` standard and has a dedicated [**Activities API**](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OpenSocial_v0.9_Activities) webpage with examples.

Once you view that page, you'll see they work within the depreciated [**OpenSocial API**](http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/spec/1.0/OpenSocial-Specification.xml) v1 Platform.

In reference to the **Stream Subscription** method your using, the History Log has the last entry at **January 2010**. It's safe to say that method has been abandoned. Reference screenshot:

[image]

I visited [**Wikipedia Myspace Page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace#MySpace_Developer_Platform_.28MDP.29) to discover what Developer API is currently used and was greeted with the same outdated information that you already have. The last API used was in 2010.

There still is hope for your goal of getting music related events via a current API method: The above Wikipedia page has a section titled [**Decline: 2008–present**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace#Decline:_2008.E2.80.93present) which links to footnote 71 for a **January 2012** article: [**MySpace is Reborn at Panasonic Press Conference, Unleashes Justin Timberlake**](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2398677,00.asp)

That Wikipedia announcement reads:

```
In January 2012, the company announced at CES that it would introduce MySpace TV with Panasonic.
```

While Myspace is currently under the radar for developers and your goal is to get **Music Related Events** (from music artists?) via API, consider using YouTube API that has a powerful search feature to find such events from artists with legitimate YouTube ID's.

If that's not an option perhaps **Myspace TV / Panasonic** venture will come into fruition soon.

As this is not a happy answer, it's only fitting to [**Cry Me A River**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DksSPZTZES0) until a new [**API**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fz1BXF7bVpM) is realized.

---

**Edit:** As your looking for a Boolean Answer, MySpace API is `false`.
To complement that Boolean state, these other JavaScript values are considered false too: `0` `-0` `null` `""` `undefined` `NaN`.

[**WordPress for MySpace API**](http://developer.myspace.com/wordpress/) is abandoned with last blog entry **April 2010**.

The [**MySpace Stream Subscription API**](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Stream_Subscription_API) is a component of [**MySpace RESTful API**](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:RESTful_API) that is abandoned.

Finally, the [**MySpace Developer Home Page**](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) was last updated on [**December 2010**](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=history).

Even to this day, [**Google Groups for MySpace API**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/myspace-apis) has no activity since **July 2010**.

The above links is **Further Evidence** that the MySpace API is dead.

Comment: Bounty is yours for making the effort.  A boolean would be false, not null, unless you're a Java programmer (my condolences).  Thanks

Comment: Thank you! JavaScript Boolean values can be tricky to grasp. While it literally boils down to `true` or `false`, other values will indirectly cause a Boolean `true` or `false`. Example: using `null` would result in Boolean `false`. Its funny that using `"false"` is Boolean `true` (It's because a string was defined). I read an article explaining the process a JavaScript Engine takes in converting these values. Also, testing for certain values may cause JavaScript Coercion (e.g., numbers). Finally, different JavaScript Engines may report different variable values such as `undefined` or `null`.